Imagemagick composite of two images results in unexpected 90º rotation of second image
this command using the first two attached images results in the third image. how is the rotation of gotg021.jpg happening?
magick composite -blend  50 gotg021.jpg gotg01150.jpg -alpha Set transition1-2-50.jpg;
(Mac Mini Monterey)

the forum tool doesn't like that my post is mostly images, so it's forcing me to add additional information, though I can't imagine anything else pertinent

above is the first image, and below, the 50%/50% composite showing the unexpected and unwanted rotation of the overlaid image


If you swap the order of the images what happens then? I'd suggest looking at source image meta data one of them may have rotate by 90 degrees set.

It could be the orientation tag or page geometry needs to be reset. Try putting "+repage" after the input file names.

Don't use magick composite. Use magick and swap the order of the input images. Then add -auto-orient after the two input images.  One image has meta data that says it was captured rotated. -auto-orient with properly rotate the image.

not sure how to blend the images without using composite -blend—is there another method that's better?

Possibly because this is not a programming question.

d'oh. of course. mea culpa. and thanks.

EXIF:Orientation was indeed set to 6 (camera was rotated 90ºCCW) on gotg02 but since that didn't match the visible orientation I used exiftool to change EXIF:Orientation
exiftool -Orientation="Horizontal" gotg02.jpg
Auto-orient didn't help because of the mismatch between visible orientation and the EXIF:Orientation setting.
